# Looping multiple classes with multiple queryselector

Tags: javascript, html

I am inputting a Show/hide span tag on my page, in which when clicked will display the paragraph below it, and hide it again when clicked again.

I have previously done this before by setting multiple ID's on the elements i.e:

```js
function pageLoad() {
  display();
  noDisplay();
}
function display() {
  var here = document.getElementById('one');
  var more = document.getElementById('show')

  function visible() {
    more.style.display = 'block';
    here.style.display = 'none';
  }
  here.addEventListener('click', visible);
}

function noDisplay() {
  var hide = document.getElementById('hide');
  var less = document.getElementById('show');
  var more = document.getElementById('one');

  function inVisible() {
    less.style.display = 'none';
    more.style.display = 'block';
  }
  show.addEventListener('click', inVisible);
}

window.onload = pageLoad();
```

```html
<p>Some Text</p>
<span id="one"> Show more... </span>
<p id="show" style="display: none;">Some more text... <br /><span id="hide">Less text</span></p>
```

However this leads to numerous excessive lines of code. So i have tried doing it with `queryselector`, Yet i cannot figure out where to input the second `queryselector` in this function. Here's my current code in a snippet, It returns an error because i do not understand where to input the second `queryselector`, so it doesn't work:

```js
function startUp() {
  showText();
}

function showText() {
  var clicker = document.getElementsByClassName('display');
  var show = document.getElementsByClassName('showandhide');
  for (let i = 0; i < clicker.length; i++) {
    clicker[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (clicker[i].querySelector('show').style.display == 'none') {
        show.style.display = 'inline-block';
      } else
        show.style.display = 'none';
    });
  };
}

window.onload = startUp;
```

```html
<p>Some Text</p><span class="display"> ...Continue reading... </span>
<p class="showandhide">Some More Text...</p>
<p>Some Text</p><span class="display"> ...Continue reading... </span>
<p class="showandhide">Some More Text...</p>
<p>Some Text</p><span class="display"> ...Continue reading... </span>
<p class="showandhide">Some More Text...</p>
```

Do I need to input another `for` loop, for the second `queryselector` somewhere, or do i need to just change the `className` after the `eventListener` to represent the class for the extra text?
This is the first time i have tried to do it this way, rather than the previous method of multiple ID's and excessive code. My searching on google for nesting `for` loops and `queryselectors` have not been beneficial.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I do not see any ID's in my HTML or JS, Nor should there be...

Comment: Oh, I assumed the first snippet included part of your current HTML. Never mind.

Comment: use an attribute data-target on your clickable span which corresponds with the paragraph you want to show. bind a click event to that span and check the data-target attribute. then set the style for the corresponding element.

Comment: @Puzzle84 Data attributes should not be used for styling, It is semantically wrong, Thank you anyway.

Comment: i'm not using them for styling. i have logic based on the data attribute execute code that happens to be showing or hiding an object. input["data-target=blah"] would be styling based on the data tag imho but hey if you want to be totally clean i'm good with that, it's a good practice

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns a HTMLCollection, you can't just call .style on it.

Comment: @Ricky Semantically, you should not be using JavaScript to set inline CSS properties on elements. You should be using the CSS [`:target` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) and do away with all of the script.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I never thought of trying it with CSS... I may try it with that shortly, But i have not given up on trying with Javascript just yet, I need to learn to understand Javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this answer so others may benefit... 
I struggled with placing the second loop for the show class, after a member broke it down into logical sections, I figured it out.

```js
function startUp() {
  showText();
}

function showText() {
  var clicker = document.getElementsByClassName('display');
  var show = document.getElementsByClassName('showandhide');
  for (let i = 0; i < clicker.length; i++) {
    clicker[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      for (let x = 0; x < show.length; x++) {
        if (show[x].style.display == "none") {
          show[x].style.display = 'inline-block';
        } else
          show[x].style.display = 'none';
      };
    });
  };
}
window.onload = startUp();
```

```css
.showandhide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Some Text...</p><span class="display"> ...Continue reading... </span>
<p class="showandhide">Some Other Text</p>
```

I had to loop through the "show" class inside the "clicker" loop, and then apply the style.

Comment: So... if you use the HTML you originally had, that means if you click on the display span, all of the paragraphs will toggle open/closed...

Comment: No, I had the class set on all "span" and "P" tags that i wanted to target, I was looping through the "span" tags with class "display", but could not change the style for the "p" tag with class "showandhide", because i was originally using a queryselector without inciting a loop for the "show" class, so in theory it should have done what you have mentioned in reality it was throwing an error of "cannot read property 'style' of null

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I just had to loop through the class "show", and then style the element. I just couldn't figure out where to place the "show" loop